# How can I find firebase auth users by email in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I need to query my Firebase Authentication store by email address and get the users (email address/login provider) associated that address (if any) it in my Flutter app.

This email will not be the current user's email, but an address they type in.

FirebaseAuth.instance doesn't have any functionality to do this. I have a feeling that it might be because the client shouldn't have access to the info of all users associated with your app.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: There is indeed no way to look up the UID based on the email address in the client-side SDKs, as that would be a security risk. You can either store the mapping in a cloud-hosted database, or wrap the relevant functionality in Firebase's (server-side) [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) in a custom API endpoint of your own.